# Why does PG_reserved flag still exist in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The `PG_reserved` flag was obsoleted way back in [2005](http://lwn.net/Articles/162860/), but still exists in the [kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/page-flags.h). And the Internet seems oblivious of the true reason of its existence. Can someone please explain what it does and why is it still in the kernel code?

Comment: For back compatibility?

Comment: Perhaps google the question title? [For example this](https://lwn.net/Articles/161204/) or an [updated version](http://lwn.net/Articles/162860/).

Comment: @WeatherVane Ironically, I actually had the [updated version](http://lwn.net/Articles/162860/) in my question. The article says and I quote:
_This function (vm_insert_page) inserts the given page into vma, mapped at the given address. It does not put out warnings, and does not require that PG_reserved be set_

Comment: @LPs Can you give an example (or where it is stated to be kept for backward compatibility?). It would really help me catch where it is still used. I am not much into the device drivers though.

Comment: @jada12276 oops sorry, I suppose it is still there so that legacy code will compile.

Comment: @WeatherVane I can understand that it exists to support legacy code. But, this means the kernel actually uses this flag for checks. I just need a good pointer on how it is used by the kernel.

Comment: You could find it in [page_alloc.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c). At line 746 you could see `PAGE_FLAGS_CHECK_AT_FREE` usage. That define could be found into [page-flags.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/page-flags.h) at line 653.

Comment: @LPs ahan, so the kernel does not allow such a page to be freed. Which is all that remains to this flag. Thanks a lot!!